# How can I use Template Toolkit on a string instead of a file?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have some strings that I am pulling out of a database and I would like to use Template Toolkit on them, but I can't seem to figure out how to use strings as TT input.  Any tips?

Thanks!

-fREW

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation explains:

> process($template, \%vars, $output, %options)
>
> The process() method is called to process a template.  The first parameter indicates the input template as one of: a filename relative to INCLUDE_PATH, if defined; **a reference to a text string containing the template text**; ...

```
       # text reference
       $tt->process(\$text)
           || die $tt->error(), "\n"
```

Comment: Ok, I got it to work.  The issue was that I was using the third param (so that I wouldn't have to output the result immediately) and forgot to make it a reference.  Here's what works:      $template->process(\$body_template, $template_vars, \$output);

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template.html#method_process):

```
# text reference
$text = "[% INCLUDE header %]\nHello world!\n[% INCLUDE footer %]";
$tt->process(\$text)
    || die $tt->error(), "\n";
```

(Looks like I should have refreshed the page before posting.)

Answer (score 2):

You may find [String::TT](http://search.cpan.org/dist/String-TT/lib/String/TT.pm) as a nicer alternative way of doing it.  Some teasers from the pod...

```
use String::TT qw/tt strip/;

sub foo {
   my $self = shift;
   return tt 'my name is [% self.name %]!';
}

sub bar {
   my @args = @_;
   return strip tt q{
      Args: [% args_a.join(",") %]
   }
}
```

and...

```
my $scalar = 'scalar';
my @array  = qw/array goes here/;
my %hash   = ( hashes => 'are fun' );

tt '[% scalar %] [% scalar_s %] [% array_a %] [% hash_h %]';
```